# Phantom suggested edits

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

Tonight I seem to be getting phantom suggested edits on the main site. I perpetually have a notification that there are edits for me to review but every time I click on it, there is nothing to review. What's going on? Is this affecting anyone else?

Comment: My guess is that someone else has gotten to the suggested edit before you have. You can check [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) to see if someone has accepted or rejected a suggested edit recently.

Comment: Also, [caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), it's always [caching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221414/214632).

Comment: I suspect it's another manifestation of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233448/for-crying-out-loud-ive-read-that-message-already), which I think is the same as [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13873/persistent-comment).

Comment: @robjohn it definitely wasn't someone getting to it before me. The edit notification was perpetually on for over an hour but there was never any edit for me to review. I would click two or three times in a minute but nothing was there.

Comment: @DanielFischer That definitely seems to be it. Guess it was just a weird bug but it's cleared up now.

Comment: I do not know whether this can be your case, but [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16857/what-is-with-that-orange-box/16858#16858) claims that the number of reviews is not shown for each user. A user might have already reviewed some tasks (or simply clicked skip) and they will still see the box with the number of review tasks will be shown.